# Gradle dependency plugin in a multi module Spring Boot project

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, dependency-management, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

What does a correct Gradle configuration look like in a multi-module project that uses the Gradle plugins `spring-boot-dependencies` and `spring-boot`?

I have the following project setup:

```
parent
  |
  + build.gradle
  |
  + alpha
  |   |
  |   + build.gradle
  |
  + beta
  |   |
  |   + build.gradle
```

- The `parent` module contains common project configuration.
- The `alpha` module is a module in which I would like to import dependencies using versions numbers specified in the [spring-boot-dependencies](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent) bom, but the result of the is a standard jar.
- The `beta` module is a module that depends on `alpha` and the result is an executable Spring Boot jar file (including all dependencies). Consequently, this project needs both the `spring-boot-dependencies` as well as the `spring-boot` plugin.

In order to keep the Gradle files DRY, I have extracted common module scripts to the parent's `build.gradle` file.

Attempts to execute `$ gradle build` using the project configuration below results in:

```
> Plugin with id 'io.spring.dependency-management' not found.
```

---

**parent gradle.build**

```
allprojects {
    group = "com.example"
    version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    ext {
        dependencyManagementPluginVersion = '0.5.3.RELEASE'
        springBootVersion = '1.3.0.RC1'
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
}

subprojects {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
            maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:${dependencyManagementPluginVersion}")
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}")
//            mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:${springBootVersion}")
        }
    }
}
```

**alpha build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework:spring-web')
}
```

**beta gradle.build**

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

dependencies {
    compile project(':alpha')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
}
```

---

Comments:

- The behavior of the `spring-boot` plugin [was changed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2133) in Spring Boot 1.3.0.M1
- Gradle version: 2.8
- Spring Boot version 1.3.0.RC1

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please upvote it.

Comment: @Opal Sorry about the delay, I thought I had accepted your answer. I have written a [blog post](http://www.jayway.com/2015/11/23/reusing-spring-boots-dependency-management/) regarding the matter, please check the acknowledgements. :-)

Comment: Thanks, exactly the problem I had --- to help others googling this issue, I will add: If you naively try: apply plugin 'spring-boot' to ALL your subprojects, (only in order to get spring dependency-management for free) you will get build-error (at least I got under windows), like:
Execution failed for task ':xxxxx:bootRepackage'.
Unable to rename 'xxxxx.jar' to 'xxxxx.jar.original'

Comment: @matsev, have just noticed info about the article - looks good. Thanks for being mentioned!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It turns out that `parent/build.gradle` should be rearranged in the following way:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        dependencyManagementPluginVersion = '0.5.3.RELEASE'
        springBootVersion = '1.3.0.RC1'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:${dependencyManagementPluginVersion}")
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

allprojects {
    group = "com.example"
    version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
}

subprojects {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}")
//          mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:${springBootVersion}")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem lies in the fact that `buildscript` block for subprojects was indeed configured well but... in a wrong place. This `subprojects` block relates to subprojects but it will be evaluated *in the script* it was declared, and there were no dependencies declared for the plugin it was trying to apply.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not quite work. Now Gradle fails to find repositories for the submodules:

`> Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.RC1 because no repositories are defined.
  Required by:
      com.example:alpha:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` 

Copying `repositories` to the `allprojects` solves the problem, but is there a way to define `repositories` _once_ so that it is accessible from both `buildscript` and `allprojects`?

Comment: No :/ Unfortunately, these are separate configurations. It needs to be duplicated.

Comment: FYI, `buildscript` applies to the `build.gradle`, not to any particular project in it, so what you found isn't surprising. But your answer doesn't do the same thing as shown in your question; the root project doesn't have `dependencyManagement` anymore.